# Change font within Chapter Title - e.g. first part black, second red

Tags: fonts, sectioning, color

Since I often use one document in two forms, lets say in form 1 and form 2, I would like to label that accordingly in the chapter headings and have parts in a different color. So the questions is, how can one change Colors within a chapter heading (I know of `sectsty`, but this seems to affect the whole and all chapter headings?)?

The following example gives an idea of what I want to achieve, but it does not work since simple text colours in headings seem to be not supported.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lions and Birds \textcolor{red}{(Document Form 1)}}
%
\newpage
%
\chapter{Alligators and Storks \textcolor{red}{(Document Form 1)}}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance and best regards, Manuel

Comment: This does not work because `\MakeUppercase` (being used in a macro behind `\chapter` transforms `red` to `RED`, which is unknown, of course -- `\textcolor` is no robust macro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The same cause why `\ref` or `\gls` in a chapter etc. title is problematic occurs with `\textcolor`: The macro `\MakeUppercase` for the chapter marks at the heading transforms `\textcolor{ref}{...}` into `\textcolor{RED}{...}` first, which is expanded to its final meaning, trying to apply an undefined (most likely) color named `RED`.

In order to prevent this, the color change must be hidden in a robust macro (or some macro prepended with `\protect`, but that might get tedious:

E.g.

```
\newrobustcmd{\redtext}[1]{%
  \textcolor{red}{#1}%
}
```

defines a macro meant for red text.

Another possibility is using the optional argument of `\chapter` and omitting the color change there, but this will not colorize the text in the ToC.

Please be aware, that mixing too much colors in text may worsen readability.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newrobustcmd{\redtext}[1]{%
  \textcolor{red}{#1}%
}

\newrobustcmd{\bluetext}[1]{%
  \textcolor{blue}{#1}%
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lions and Birds \redtext{(Document Form 1)}}

\chapter{Cats and mice \bluetext{(Document Form 2)}}

\chapter[Cows and goats]{Cows and goats \textcolor{brown}{(Document Form 3)}}

\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Christian! This works perfectly fine for me. Since I only plan to use two different colors in headings, defining two robust colors is no issue.

Comment: @Manuel: You can also use a macro `\formone` and `\formtwo`, which does the formatting of your forms without typing the `(...)` as well and you can simply change the colors inside the `\form...` macros instead of switching `\redtext` to another macro name -- this depends on your design what `form 1` and `form 2` are supposed to do, however

Answer (score 0):

May be I have missed something! I have just add `\usepackage{xcolor}` to the OP MWE preamble and I get this output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor} % I add this line 

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lions and Birds \textcolor{red}{(Document Form 1)}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The issue is that the header uses an ALL-CAPS form of the chapter title and will try to find the colour RED, which does not exists. The problem only becomes apparent if you add a second page to the MWE so that you get a page with an actual header. (See also Christian's answer.)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I should have included an additional page, in the original example (now edited).

Comment: @Manuel Note that a colour package (`color` or `xcolor`) is also needed (I edited it in). Please always test your MWEs before you submit them and make sure the show the *same* error you receive in your real document.

Comment: Thanks, that's true. I did get an error, but it was not the same...